# How can I sort Json properties in a spring RestController

Tags: java, json, sorting, properties, spring-restcontroller

I have a huge `Map<String, Object>` that is the return type of a spring RestController action.
The map is basically String - String pairs with a String - Map called context.
I would like to sort the output json to the context be the first.
I found the `@JsonPropertyOrder` as a solution when the returned object has properties. Unfortunately it is not working with my Map.

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping("/test.json")
    @JsonPropertyOrder(value = {"context"}, alphabetic = true)
    public Map<String, Object> response() {
        Map<String, String> context = new HashMap<>();
        context.put("environment", "dev");
        Map<String, Object> myMap = new HashMap<>();
        myMap.put("context", context);
        myMap.putAll(fillMyMap());
        return myMap;
    }

    private Map<String, String> fillMyMap() {
        Map<String, String> myMapFillValues = new HashMap<>();
        myMapFillValues.put("test", "foo");
        myMapFillValues.put("test2", "bar");
        return myMapFillValues;
    }
}
```

So I want the output like this

```
{
    "context": {
        "environment": "dev"
    },
    "test": "foo",
    "test2": "bar"
}
```

instead of this:

```
{
    "test": "foo",
    "test2": "bar",
    "context": {
        "environment": "dev"
    }
}
```

Comment: you cannot do this with HashMap, as it does not maintain order. If you care about order, you can try LinkedHashMap, or other map that maintains order. Check if linkedHashMap works

Comment: Wouldn't that annotation just say to alphabetize the items *within* `context`?

Comment: @mlecz - Thx, it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Specify the order on the parent.

@JsonPropertyOrder({ "context", "test", "test2" })

public class Foo {

Same thing for alphabetic
https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonPropertyOrder.html

@JsonPropertyOrder(alphabetic=true)

public class Foo {

Comment: As I said I don't have any custom object with properties. I have a Map, so I couldn't specify the JsonPropertyOrder on the parent.
BTW: I have aprox 4-500 String - String pairs in my map. So I don't really want to create a custom object with properties. ;)

Answer (score 0):

For Spring Boot, add

```
spring.jackson.serialization.order-map-entries-by-keys=true
```

to the `application.properties` file.

Answer (score 0):

`LinkedHashMap` will output to json the same order at putting.
You put in order {"1", "3", "2"} -> Json get in order {"1", "3", "2"}. Neither ASC or DESC

So

```
Map<String, String> myMapFillValues = new LinkedHashMap<>();
```

Instead of

```
Map<String, String> myMapFillValues = new HashMap<>();
```